# Rounded Rect's in custom cell, UITableViewController while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, rounded-corners

While referencing [UIImage with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563986/uiimage-with-rounded-corners) I'm able to create images that have rounded rects. This has definitely helped my scroll refresh rates.

The problem I now have is that I generally use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` while drawing my `UIImages` into view's.

Drawing with a `UIBezierPath` and then putting the image in its bounds is making the image loose its aspect ratio.

```
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds 
                    cornerRadius:10.0] addClip];

[image drawInRect:imageView.bounds];
```

Is the only way out by writing a custom scale solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you just need to set a rounded corners to your image, you can try setting the CornerRadius of your image layer. Did you try that out?

Comment: @GenieWanted using CornerRadius in a UITableVieController slows down scrolling motion. If the image is moving iOS has to keep re-drawing the image. The solution is to create a new image which has rounded edges and then display that. user903362 solution worked great since it fixed the aspect ratio of the scaled image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GSize size1 = image.size;
CGSize size2 = imageView.bounds.size;
CGRect newRect;
if (size1.width / size1.height > size2.width / size2.height) {
    CGFloat newWidth = size2.height * size1.width / size1.height;
    newRect = CGRectMake((size2.width - newWidth)/2, 0, newWidth, size2.height);
} else {
    CGFloat newHeight = size1.height / size1.width * size2.width;
    newRect = CGRectMake(0, (size2.height - newHeight)/2, size2.width, newHeight);
}
[image drawInRect:newRect];
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at using layer compositing if possible, instead of trying to draw the whole thing yourself. For example:

- Create a `CALayer` with a roundrect content
- Use a standard way of presenting the image (i.e. `UIImageView`)
- Set the [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask) property of the image layer to the roundrect layer

See [this article](http://evandavis.me/blog/2013/2/13/getting-creative-with-calayer-masks) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method you reference uses the image view's bounds as the size of the image context, and it might not have the right aspect ratio, so you need to set the size of the image view first, before passing it in. So, if you want all the image views to have the same width, pass in that width, and a height that's determined from that width and the aspect ratio of the image.

CGFloat height = imageView.bounds.size.width * (image.size.width/image.size.height);