# Xcode making a pdf, trying to round corners

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, pdf

I am making a pdf in an iPad app. Now i can make the pdf however want to add a picture with a rounded corner border. For example to achieve the effect i want on the border on a simple view item i use the following code.

```
self.SaveButtonProp.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
self.SaveButtonProp.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
self.SaveButtonProp.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
self.SaveButtonProp.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
```

With the pdf i am using the following method to add the picture with the border to the pdf.

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageWithData : Image];
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(20, 125, 200, 200);
[demoImage drawInRect:rectFrame];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 2);
CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
```

How do i round the corners?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While drawing you can set clipping masks. For example, it's relatively easy to create a Bezier path with the shape of a rounded rectangle and apply that as clipping mask to your graphics context. Everything subsequently drawn will be clipped.

If you want remove the clipping mask later (for example because you have an image with rounded corners but follow that by other elements) you'll have to save the graphic state first, then apply your clipping mask and restore the graphics state when you're done with your rounded corners.

You can see actual code that comes pretty close to what I think you need here:
[UIImage with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563986/uiimage-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to get any UIView/UIImageView to PDF NSData:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    NSData *data = [self makePDFfromView:imageView];
```

Method:

```
- (NSData *)makePDFfromView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

Maybe you can change or use this code to help you with your problem.