# How to round WKInterfaceImage's corners in an  Watch app?

Tags: xcode, imageview, watchkit, apple-watch

There're lot of  Watch apps which has rounded corners for their WKInterfaceImages. I'm trying to round even some WKInterfaceImages in my test app but I can't understand how to do that.

I can't work with imageView.layer. ... as with normal iPhone apps and I can't find an alternative to do that using code or storyboard.

Do I have to mask all PNGs or there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right `CALayer` and `UIView` are not directly available on watchOS 2. But you are able to use graphic functions and for instance [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995999/3242031) is perfectly acceptable on Watch.

The analogue in Swift:

```
class ImageTools {
    class func imageWithRoundedCornerSize(cornerRadius:CGFloat, usingImage original: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, original.size.width, original.size.height)

        // Begin a new image that will be the new image with the rounded corners
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(original.size, false, 1.0)

        // Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()

        // Draw the new image
        original.drawInRect(frame)

        // Get the new image
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // Lets forget about that we were drawing
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return roundedImage
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your `WKInterfaceController` class:

```
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "original-image")!
let roundedImage = ImageTools.imageWithRoundedCornerSize(60, usingImage: originalImage)

// Set `UIImage` for your `WKInterfaceImage`
imageOutlet.setImage(roundedImage)
```

Comment: @Matte.Car - I've updated the link with a more appropriate example for Watch.

Comment: It could even work but it's in Objective-C... I tried translating it but I can't...

Comment: @Matte.Car  - Added the example in Swift. It works perfectly.

Comment: Wow! I'm trying to test it but, I can't undestand why, using `row.flagView.setImageNamed(codice)` works great, but using `let immagine = UIImage(named: codice)!` return a nil value...

Comment: This is a totally different question - try to clean your cache or something.

Answer (score 2):

I solved removing the WKInterfaceImage from storyboard then replacing it with an WKInterfaceGroup which I set with same sizes of previous Image then, from attribute inspector, I setted his radius (yes, with groups it's possible!) then I declared group in controller and setted the image using                 `row.flagView.setBackgroundImageNamed(imageName)`.

Comment: Actually I knew it :) But thought the question was about WKInterfaceImage. Anyway I'm glad to hear that you solved your problem!

Comment: Yeah, mine it's a trick! I'll keep this question open if someone find a real solution for asked question.