# How to set corner Radius to UIImage not UIImageView in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, cornerradius

Can any one help me...! I just want to set a corner radius to an image and also the image has to be fit in AspectFit scale.

If I give scaleToFill mode I can use the below code and its working fine. but the image is been Stretched.

```
self.productImg.layer.cornerRadius = 7
self.productImg.clipsToBounds = true
```

But when giving the scale to AspectFit it is showing as shown in below image.

The green color showing is the image View, and within that the image is setting to aspectFit.

The Actual image

[image: Actual image]

The Image when giving the aspectFit mode

[image: Image when giving the aspectFit mode]

i need the image as it is actually given and also it has to be with corner radius. So please any one give me solution to Resolve this.

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: have you set background color of UIIMageVIew ?

Comment: yes, but it is for highlighting the imageview to you. (for post)

Comment: ok please refer this link if it helps to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563986/uiimage-with-rounded-corners

Comment: Tried it out. Same problem persists.

Comment: Still I didn't find a right solution for this question..! can anyone help me in this case....?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is an extension for UIImage to set corner radius for it, not dealing with UIImageView.

```
extension UIImage {
    // image with rounded corners
    public func withRoundedCorners(radius: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let maxRadius = min(size.width, size.height) / 2
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat
        if let radius = radius, radius > 0 && radius <= maxRadius {
            cornerRadius = radius
        } else {
            cornerRadius = maxRadius
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).addClip()
        draw(in: rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
yourUIImage.withRoundedCorners(radius: 10)
```

Comment: Code only answers are not answers; provide explanation, please (and format correctly).

Comment: what is size in line 4 ?!

Comment: size is a property of UIImage (self.size, where self is UIImage). it is available, because we are inside extension of UIImage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try AspectFill mode, instead of AspectFit.
Using AspectFill, image will fill imageView completely, and there'll be rounded corners.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. but with this the image is getting cropped. (The full image is not showing)

Comment: In this case, if it's necessary to show complete image, without cutting any little piece of it, you should set proper constraints for your imageView in storyboard.
Check aspect ratio of your image (in Photoshop eg), and set constraint "Aspect Ratio" for your imageView to the same value.

Comment: I've Tried it out. Same problem persists.

Answer (score -2):

Similar to Anton's answer, but with a small twist:

Place the UIImageView in a generic UIView, which acts as a container whose corner radius you can control.

Example:

```
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true //maybe not necessary
//set some width and height in a CGRect()

let imageView = UIImageView()
containerView.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.frame = containerView.bounds
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```